# Error al crear apk Program type already present

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este error y no se porque, me dice algo de cardview que ni siquiera estoy usando:

Program type already present: android.support.v7.cardview.R$attr
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v7.cardview.R$attr, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Este mensaje no indica nada, agrega tu configuración build.gradle